# Troubleshooting Http compresstion for PHP on iis7

Tags: php, iis-7, gzip

Simply checking "Enable dynamic content compression" in iis7 has no effect on the transmitted size of my .php files (confirmed via Firebug and Fiddler).

This is in spite of this brief article here that suggests it really is that simple: http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/IIS-775-FastCGI-hosting-PHP-and-Compression.aspx

I followed this forum post http://forums.iis.net/t/1159141.aspx but could not trace anything that suggested compression failed.

Should I just give up and use PHP's "zlib" compression instead?

Comment: Are you sure it's not in effect? Post your HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your .config file to make sure you have the right application/json entries in dynamicTypes.

For reasons we haven't figured out yet our IIS server has some variability in its Content-Type response headers and you need to exactly match what IIS is spitting out otherwise it won't compress the content, ala:

```
  <dynamicTypes>
       ...
       <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
       <add mimeType="application/json; q=0.5" enabled="true" />
       <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
       <add mimeType="application/json; q=0.5; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
       ...
  </dynamicTypes>
```

If you're still having no luck, please post your full HTTP Response headers.

Comment: Gak... that's what I get for trying to use a similar response for two questions! :(Probably not application/json in your case, but the fix is the same - you need to exactly match whatever IIS is putting in the HTTP Response's Content-Type header or it won't match here to enable dynamic content compression.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a bunch!I got the gist from your original answer, added text/html, text/css, application/x-javascript and things are working nice now.